# geolocation component for joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla

Does anyone know a geolocation component for Joomla?

I need to show specific contents for some countries and other contents for other countries like articles, modules and components.

I found this [plugin](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/visitors/16090).

But I'm not sure how should this plugin help me to do that, does anyone use it before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Best way I found for creating a geolocation content website using joomla is by using [geolok plugin](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/visitors/16090)  and [moduletopages module](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/modules-management/13140).

you can create rules for displaying the homepage modules depends on the visitor country.
the only limit in this way you can't display article in the frontpage directly, you must display it using module like [News Show Pro GK4](http://tools.gavick.com/)

I hope my answer will help other developers

Best Regards
Fadi